# Linux Script to move directories containing a file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep

Fairly new to scripting in linux, so I'm hoping this is something simple. I need to move a directory containing several files to another location if that directory contains a file with a certain piece of text in it.

I have a command that gives me a list of directories matching my criteria here:

```
find . -name 'file.name' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "foo" | sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#' | sort -u
```

Now I just need to take the results of this and combine them with an mv command inside of an executable script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xargs` with substitution to get the desired effect:

```
commands to get directory list | xargs -i mv "{}" <destination>
```

Comment: this one ended up being my solution because it handled directory names with spaces and special characters easily, thanks

Answer (score 2):

assuming ALL that comes out of the pipeline you posted is the directory name:

```
$target=/home/me/example
find . -name 'file.name' -print0 | 
xargs -0 grep -l "foo" | 
sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#' | 
while read line #line is a variable with the contents of one line
do
    mv $line $target
done
```

Oh and get rid of the sort -u 
there is no need for it to move the directories and  it 'serializes' your pipeline, you cant sort until the find is *finished* so the moves don't start,  without it the moves can start as SOON as the 1st item is found.

Comment: well, it worked until my directories had spaces in their names... ended up working with the xargs option below

Comment: 'mv "$line" "$target"' but agree the xargs option is better here
This while read structure _can_ be useful for complex processing but I need to use xargs more

Answer (score 0):

The [backtick operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04) evaluates a command and places the `stdout` as though you'd entered it on the command line. So, in your case:

```bash
mv `find . -name 'file.name' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "foo" | sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#'` target
```